Harmonic function agreeing on the boundary with a subharmonic function - existence?
A subharmonic function $g$ on the annulus is given and $U$ is defined to be a harmonic function agreeing on both boundary circles with $g$. I was wondering how to prove the existence of $U$. I'd appreciate any hints.
Context: this is a part of the proof of theorem 1.6 from Theory of $H^p$ Spaces by Peter Duren, without the mentioning of existence.

Note that the subharmonic function in question is continuous (as we are away from $\vert z \vert=1$). Thus, you are asking about the existence of solutions of the following boundary value problem
$$ \begin{cases} \Delta U(z) =0,& z\in \Omega,\\ U(z)=g(z),& z\in \partial \Omega, \end{cases} $$
where $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open, bounded domain with $C^1$ boundary and $g$ is continuous.
This is a standard fact in elliptic PDEs (though not trivial to prove and I am a bit puzzled by this as Duren claims his book to be self-contained). For example this can be found in Evan's PDE book (Theorem $12$).
